# How can I detect which hotbar slot a player is selected when all the hotbar slots are empty?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I'm creating a datapack that needs to detect when the player has a specific hotbar slot selected. The issue is, I also need all hotbar slots to be empty. Is there any way to do this?